# Bootstrap navbar with dropdown menu in wrong locale

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been using dropdown with bootstrap, and yesterday I had the idea to use `navbar`. In general, it worked very well, but the location of the menu is wrong, cutting all the menu items by half. (as you can see in the image).

[image]

I already use the class `dropdown-menu-right` and it solves the problem, but with `navbar`, it didn't work.

This is the code of the `nav-link` that contains the wrong dropdown:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown mx-1">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown-98324708" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Fake button to open the menu
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown-98324708">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> this is a fake item</a>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Anyone have any idea what I need to do to change the location?

(I'm using Bootstrap 4)